# Troubleshoot Windows Update service

Tags: windows-7, cpu, windows-update, services

On my Windows 7 computer, I had noticed that one of the four CPUs was running around 100%, spending ±25% of my PCs CPU.
As the number was slightly changing, I knew that it was not an infinite loop, so I started investigating.

Using standard Windows task manager, I saw that the process which was doing this, was a "svchost.exe" process. Following its process ID (PID) to the "Services" tab, I could derive that the "netsvcs" Windows service group was responsible. In order to know which of the subscribed services was responsible, I started up "Process Explorer" (a third-party extended task manager), which led me to the "wuauServ" Windows service. I have stopped it and the CPU dropped immediately, so I've found the service, causing the issue.

Now I would like to go further: the Windows Update service (wuauServ) seems to have problems (hence the high CPU), but nothing seems to be written to the event log (at least not to the "Windows Logs/Application" event log).

Does anybody know how I can find out what is causing the high CPU load of the Windows Update Service?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It isn't an issue. The windows update service doesn't know how to use more then one core and when it is running most of the time it uses the whole core.

Comment: The fact that it is taking a lot of CPU means, in my humble opinion, that something is wrong. As far as I can judge, Windows update just needs to verify some versions and in case a more recent version is found, make sure that the PC gets subscribed for update on next shutdown or restart. This does not look like a big challenge for the CPU. So what is the CPU doing all that time and in case it's having issues, how can I know which issues they are? (is there a logfile for the Windows Update?)

Comment: read the duplicate link and install the newer WU clients

Comment: It literally needs to go thru every update each time it looks for new ones, Windows update is not designed to be efficient, it only uses one core and most of the time it uses all of it